# Select all ID tags containing a certain string in coffeescript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to find the coffeescript version of the below Jquery

```
$('input[id*="contact_date"]').datepicker();
```

I have a rails form that the user can use to create several nested records, which contain a field where "contact_date" is part of the id for a date field. I'd like to add the date picker to all those fields.

An example of the date id would be "investor_investor_contacts_attributes_1392640934673_contact_date"

Any advice would be great. Sort of new at jquery & coffeescript.

Comment: Please provide more information or this issue could be flagged. Please exactly describe the issue you have, and what you have tried. Thanks

Comment: sorry! I added more context. As for what I've tried, basically been searching around for coffeescript tutorials to be honest, I've been using coffeescript since about last tuesday.

Comment: This user is new at jquery and possibly javascript, please be lenient with the vote down button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can use regex match in jquery selectors. What i advise you to do is to put a class selector on each input that you whant do add datapicker to and select them as following:

```
$('.contact_date').datepicker
```

Other solution would be to put all inputs in a div block and select all children:

```
$('#id_of_your_div').childern.datepicker
```

The only difference between coffescript and javascript code in your case is that in coffescript you can drop the ().

Comment: add a class. duh. Thanks for that!

Comment: Hi there, when I converted to coffeescript "$('.contact_date').datepicker" doesn't seem to be working. Jquery itself does so no biggie, just wondering if you have any idea why. Thanks again for the help.